# jQuery .each() just returning the last element of PHP array

Tags: php, jquery, json, each

Currently I am trying to return a PHP array in jQuery to use each element as a paremeter, 
but actually I just get the last element of *date*.

I am quite new to jQ so modest knowledge and google skills won't help at all.

Here is my snippet as now.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var date = '<?php echo json_encode($date);?>';
    var fam =  '<?php echo json_encode($fam);?>';

    $.each($.parseJSON(date),function(){
        document.write(this);
    });

    </script>
```

Array for reference is

```
Array ( [0] => 22.06.2015 [1] => 23.06.2015 [2] => 24.06.2015 [3] => 25.06.2015 [4] => 26.06.2015 [5] => 29.06.2015 [6] => 30.06.2015 )
```

Thanks in advance,

JaHem

**UPDATE**

I don't think this is a problem of .each() anymore.
After I included the PHP-file in my jQuery-file

`ob_start();
        include("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/awesome_path/application114/frames.php");
ob_end_clean();`

The `$date` array goes from `Array ( [0] => 22.06.2015 [1] => 23.06.2015 [2] => 24.06.2015 [3] => 25.06.2015 [4] => 26.06.2015 [5] => 29.06.2015 [6] => 30.06.2015 )` 
 to 
 `Array ( [0] => 30.06.2015 )`

Can there be some trouble in the `include` ?

Comment: Can you show your `$date` array that comes initially?

Comment: what is this  function(index, value{document.write(this);}); because i see  function(index, value{...}) and not function(index, value){..}

Comment: Syntax error missed closing parenthesis in each loop `$.each($.parseJSON(date),function(index, value){document.write(this);});`

Comment: My fault. I corrected the syntax.

Comment: @JaHem - still not working?

Comment: Try assigning parsed value to temp object this way: `var obj = $.parseJSON(date); console.log(obj);`. What object do you get in console?

Comment: if so, try function(i,v){
      document.write(v);
      }

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix, no - still not the required result. The mistake was just in this snippet.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev There is only the last element of the array in the console.log - ["30.06.2015"]

Comment: can you look at the page source and see what exactly  var date = '<?php echo json_encode($date);?>'; looks like in the actual page.  I think you can do away with the ' quotes and the parseJson completely.

Comment: Could you copy the generated HTML code at line `var date = '<?php echo json_encode($date);?>';`?

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Thank you for this line, but there is still no change.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev in _var date_ there is just one element.
Without the quotes I would get no return.

Comment: @JaHem It means that something's wrong with your `$date` during PHP page generation. Could you show your PHP code?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev But print_r($date) fetches the right result.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev

`$dateQuery = oci_parse($conn, ""); 
 oci_execute($dateQuery);
       
 $date = array();
 while ($row = oci_fetch_array($dateQuery,OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
        foreach ($row as $item) {
         array_push($date, $item);
        }
       }`

Please ignore the missing statement.

Comment: @JaHem can you post sample $date array?

Comment: If we have eliminated PHP at fault here would it be possible to have a [JsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) of the generated HTML?

Comment: @new_bee_magento please see above - there is a sample

Comment: @doveyg Unfortunately I am not able to reproduce this in JsFiddle

Comment: Why cant you reproduce it in JsFiddle? Does it work in JsFiddle? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @doveyg There were no erros in my console.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't quite reproduce your issue, but you could consider using JSON literals instead of strings; this way you don't need to parse it again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var dates = <?= json_encode($date) ?>;

$.each(dates, function() {
    document.write(this);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no difference in the result.

Comment: @JaHem You have to be more specific, what exactly do you see and what was the array passed in, i.e. `var_export($date)`; also, you really shouldn't use `document.write()` ... try using `console.log()` instead.

Comment: `array ( 0 => '30.06.2015', ) `

This is the result of the var_export from my array, but print_r()'d there should be data from 20.06.2015 to 30.06.2015. However I just get the last element of the PHP array in jQuery.


To `console.log()`:
I need all elements of this array as parameters in a function.
How can I just "write" ( ? ) them in a function ( just like an echo in PHP ) ?

Comment: @JaHem It almost seems that you're running this stuff from within a loop?

Comment: could you please take a look at my updated question ?

Comment: @JaHem That's not helping much; if you feel the problem is in PHP, provide the code that will reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dateArr = $.parseJSON(date);
$.each(dateArr, function(i, d) {
    console.log("Index: " + i);
    console.log("Date: " + d);
});
```

Edit: Please try to avoid document.write in the feature. Instead use console.log

Comment: Sure, but I still have some problems with the PHP array. ( could there be some trouble with json ? )

Comment: I didn't get any return values in the console with the PHP array.

Comment: i will have a pc on front of me after a couple of hours. will have a closer look then. post your code of the array and how you encode it into json. i assume that the json is throwing an error

Answer (score 0):

I assumed the array as below and it works fine:

```
<?php
    $array = array( 0 => '22.06.2015', 1 => '23.06.2015', 2 => '24.06.2015', 3 => '25.06.2015', 4 => '26.06.2015', 5 => '29.06.2015', 6 => '30.06.2015' );

?>
```

Below is the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){

    var arr = '<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>';

    arr = $.parseJSON(arr);
    $.each(arr, function(key, value) {

        console.log(key+'====>'+value);

    });

});
    </script>
```

Comment: If there was a problem with the array, `json_encode()` would fail and so would `parseJSON()`.

Comment: With a static array it works very well, but with the spezific array ( please see above [ this is a Result from an Oracledatabase ] ) I won't the required result. There is no difference to my own snippet.

Comment: @JaHem where is the oracle database result, post it on your question

Comment: @new_bee_magento you can see the resultset print_r()'d in the question.

Comment: @JaHem I cant find the result set anywhere, whats the problem to edit the question and post the result set?

Comment: @new_bee_magento `Array ( [0] => 22.06.2015 [1] => 23.06.2015 [2] => 24.06.2015 [3] => 25.06.2015 [4] => 26.06.2015 [5] => 29.06.2015 [6] => 30.06.2015 )` this is the parsed result

Comment: @JaHem are you getting the result exactly like this, I mean dates not within single quotes?

Comment: @new_bee_magento yes, i just "hit" it like this

Comment: @new_bee_magento please see the update in the question

Comment: @new_bee_magento frames.php is the mainfile of this project.

With 
`<script type="text/javascript">
$("#chart").html('<object id="chart" data="/awesome_Path/js/Highcharts/examples/line-basic/lines.php #container">');
</script>`
I include my `#container` from the seperat jQuery-file to show the the result in a div in the frames.php.

Comment: @new_bee_magento there is just this `$date` in frames.php.

Could you please take a short look at the updated question ?